# Foreign key, or no foreign key? Defining Laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

What is the difference between **defining a foreign key** VS **just creating an integer column** named `user_id`?

```
// create_posts migrations
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
// vs
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Can they be used interchangeably? What purpose do each one serve? Which is considered a best practice, first or second definition?

### Edit

The command `$post->user()` will work either ways, so what advantages does usage of a foreign key bring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
// Above command is creating a column in database and it is required to have the required table structure

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
// Above command is creating foreign key index and making reference to id in users table.
```

As you can see from command explanations **they can't be interchangeable**, you need first command to have second command **without first second command would complain**.

**Best practise** is to **use both of them** together.

Few of advantages are listed below:

1. You can implement ***cascade update/delete***.
2. ***Database level validation*** that only valid values of user_id is recorded ( to avoid some one entering 999999 which might be invalid or non existing user_id).

Above two are main advantages and you can express multiple scenarios how above two can be life saviour.

Let's say in post table by human error or bug in script makers user_id = 9999. What you think $post->user() will do?

Unless you can have a post without any reference to user you can see there could be multiple logical issue you may find if foreign keys are not used.

***Think of foreign keys as enforcing relations and taking care of post if user is removed / deleted from db.***

Answer (score 0):

No, They can't be used interchangeably and each one has its usage. Use index when you want to define index on column, means database index, see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html). But when you define a foreign key it set a index to that column (for searching, ...) and also make a relation between user_id and id column in user table, so if there is a user by id 10, then you can use user_id = 10 on another table. Also it has another benefits such as making sure your data are integrated. For example you can't delete user by id 10 if there is article that belongs to this user. For more information [see this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-foreign-keys.html).

Answer (score -1):

The first line, will only create a user_id column not something special,
while the other line will create a column as a foreign key which will be tightly coupled with id column of users table, this will create some limitations.
read about foreign key [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Why would I want to use the second column if only thing it does is creating limitations?

Comment: thats up to you how do you want your system to be made, by limitations i mean that you cant delete the record from users table because of this foreign key reference, again its all about the system, according to me the more system is loosely coupled the more you have room for expanding it..

Answer (score -1):

For the best practices I always use:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Don't mix the definition of index with foreign key, they don't mean the same.

Comment: Why is it a best practice?

Comment: Because you can read better that your user_id is an unsigned integer.
If you write $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned() you need to read a lot more code in order to realize that your user_id is unsigned.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about the usage of a foreign key. Though usage of `unsignedInteger` looks very neat